вылезает ошибка при написание js Incorrect use of <label for=FORM_ELEMENT>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>js</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="main"method="post"  onsubmit="return checkForm(this)" >
    <label for="name">Имя:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" id="name"><br><br>
    <label for="password">Пароль:</label>
    <input type="password"  name="pass" placeholder="Паоль" id="pass"><br><br>
    <label for="repass">Проверка пароля:</label>
    <input type="password"  name="repass" placeholder="Проверка пароля" id="repass"><br><br>
    <span>Пол:</span>
    <input type="radio" name="state" id="male" value="Мужской">
    <label for="male">Мужской</label>
    <input type="radio" name="state" id="female" value="Женский">
    <label for="female">Женский</label><br><br>
    <div id="eroor" style="color: brown;"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Готово">

    </form>
    <script src="js/baba.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


function checkForm(el) {

    var name = el.name.value;
    var pass = el.pass.value;
    var repass = el.repass.value;
    var state = le.state.value;

    var fail
    if ( name == "" || pass == "" || state == "")
        fail = "Заполните все поля";
    else if (name.length <=1 || name.length > 50 )
        fail = "Введите коректное время";
    else if (pass != repass)
        fail = "Пороль не совпадают! ";
    else if (pass.split ("!@#$%^&*()_+=").length > 1)
        fail = "НЕльзя вводить знаки: !@#$%^&*()_+="

        if (fail != " ") {
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = fail;

            return false;
        } else {
            alert("Все данные коректны");
          return true;
        }
}



Приведенный кусок кода не соответствует ошибке и ошибка явно не из-за js. Это вас браузерер предупреждает, что есть лейбл без указанного элемента.

спасибо. я слышал то что у каждого браузера по разному , как это исправить и можете ли вы указать точно куда надо написать этот лейбл

Почитайте внимательно про тэг label

У вас label for=password, а у поля с паролем id=pass
